# Add a user row to an existing grid or table on button click

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I have created a page that has one GridView and one Form. My GridView is working properly.
My form has a TextBox for User Name or Email address and a submit button. This form is also working properly.

Below this form, I need to create a Table or Grid to store each User name and Email that was added.
How can I create this table that in such a way that one line is added for each  `btnSendUser_OnClick` event? This table must not delete rows that were inserted previously.
My table now shows just one row (the most recent).

My aspx

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" GridLines="None"
        CssClass="table table-bordered table-striped">
        <Columns>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="AccessGroup" HeaderText="Access Group" />
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Business Justification">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtJustBuss" runat="server" Height="17px" Width="150px"></asp:TextBox>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
        </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>
    <asp:Label ID="lblUserAdd" runat="server" Font-Bold="true" Text="Add User - (Email or User Name)"></asp:Label>
    <br />
    <asp:TextBox ID="txtUserAdd" runat="server" Height="17px" Width="150px"></asp:TextBox>
    <asp:Label ID="lblError" runat="server" class="control-label" for="inputError" Visible="false">Input with error</asp:Label>
    <asp:Button ID="btnAddUser" class="btn" runat="server" Font-Bold="true" Text="Add User"
        OnClick="btnSendUser_OnClick" />
    <br />
    <br />
    <table id="tblUsers" class="table table-bordered table-striped" runat="server" visible="false">
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <asp:Label ID="lblUser" runat="server" Visible="false"></asp:Label>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <asp:Label ID="lblEmail" runat="server" Visible="false"></asp:Label>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

My .cs

```
protected void btnSendUser_OnClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string LoginInfo = txtUserAdd.Text;
    PrincipalContext insPrincipalContext = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, "x.com", "amsuser", "xx");
    UserPrincipal insUserPrincipal = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(insPrincipalContext, LoginInfo);

    if (insUserPrincipal == null)
    {
        lblError.Visible = true;
    }

    else
    {
        tblUsers.Visible = true;
        lblUser.Visible = true;
        lblEmail.Visible = true;
        lblUser.Text = insUserPrincipal.GivenName + " " + insUserPrincipal.Surname;
        lblEmail.Text = insUserPrincipal.EmailAddress;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use a component that is designed to deal with a collection of values - for example another grid.

If that is too heavy, you can just update the labels like this:

```
lblUser.Text = lblUser.Text 
             + insUserPrincipal.GivenName + " " + insUserPrincipal.Surname
             + "<br />";
lblEmail.Text = lblEmail.Text
              + insUserPrincipal.EmailAddress
              + "<br />";
```